# $stateProvider angularJs not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have button on my page as below:

```
<button ui-sref=".viewer({maId: gridItem.MAID})" class="btn btn-info">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
</button>
```

On click I`d like to change state with ui-sref. I am currently on state /status and I want to go into /status/{maId} state.

Here is my routes.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
    .module('MA.status')
    .config(function ($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('status', {
                url: '/status',
                controller: 'Status as vm',
                templateUrl: 'app/pages/status/status.html?v=0.0.1'
            })
            .state('status.viewer', {
                url: '/:maId',
                controller: "Viewer as vm",
                templateUrl: 'app/pages/status/viewer.html?v=0.0.1',
                resolve: {
                    maId: function ($stateParams) {
                      return ($stateParams.id);
                   }
            }
            });
    });
})();
```

When I click the button url changes but html doesnt change it is still templateUrl from status state not status/{maId}. There are no errors in console.

What`s the issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Your ui-sref on your button should be like this:

```
<button ui-sref="status.viewer({maId: gridItem.MAID})" class="btn btn-info">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
</button>
```

You always have to insert the whole state name which is declared in your routes.

**EDIT:**

Without seeing your whole HTML structure based on your comment I would guess you are missing the `ui-view` directive in your status state template. If you're using child states the parent needs to have it for it to be able to show the content/template of the child. You could set the `status.viewer` state as a whole separate state if you would like it to work the way you have it now. But if you want it as a child state just add this somewhere in your `status` state and the content of the child state will appear.

```
<div ui-view></div>
```

So make the `ui-sref` change and add the `ui-view` to your parent state template.

Comment: still the same result :(